# Confusion about delegates in ios objective-c programming

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I'm very new to objective-C and iOS development. I have some confusion. Im following a tutorial and he creates a UITableView in the IB. He then adds the protocols for connecting the new TableView object to the viewcontroller as such:

```
   @interface viewController:UIViewCOntroller <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewData>
```

Then he fulfills a required method for one of the protocols as such in the viewController implementation:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

My question is pretty simple, what are each of the identifiers in this definition. My understanding is that the required method is "cellForRowAtIndexPath". from what I know about objective-c this syntax would imply that tableView is the name of this method and it returns (UITableViewCell) and takes a UITableView object "tableView". I know that can't be correct if the method that needs to be implemented is "cellForRowAtIndexPath".   After that the syntax is confusing me. I feel dumb, I've been programming for years and I can't get my head around some of these xcode and iOS app structure concepts. Basically I just need full clarification on this syntax. Thanks.

Comment: The "name" is actually `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` not `tableView` (the tableview wants to pass the instance to it's delegate, as the delegate might be working on behalf of more than one tableview, hence the selector begins with `tableView`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way. Delegates / Protocols in Objective C are nothing more than an interface in OOP.

Objective C is a very verbose language. Initially, it sucks to understand but once you go past the culture shock, there's a descriptive beauty to it which I love.

Your method isn't 'tableView'. Your method is "A tableView wants to know what cell to render for this indexPath'. See what I mean?

The way you write methods (or messages, in Objective C) for iOS is very descriptive.

In Java, you'd pass in multiple parameters like:

`methodName(type1 param1, type2 param2, ...)`

In Objective C, it's:

`- (returnType)thisMethodDoesThingsWhichNeeds:(type1)thingIneed1 andAnotherThingItNeedsIs:(type2)thingINeed2 ....`

Going by this methodology, what's happening in your case is this:

- You need a tableView on your viewController
- Right. A tableView can't think for itself. It needs someone to take care of rendering and building cells for it (the viewController).
- It also needs a dataSource (your viewController again).
- So you tell the tableView on your nib file that this viewController is it's delegate, and dataSource.
- Now, when you allocate your tableView, it knows that it's delegate and dataSource properties are ready, so it starts messaging your objects things like
  :

  a. I need to know how many rows I have in a particular section -
  `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`

  b. Hey I need to know what the height of this row is -
  `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

  c. Hey can someone tell me what to do when a user selected this cell - `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

... and so on

Also, you notice how I wrote down the methods? It's not just `tableView`... it's `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That's what your method is.

Empty your mind and try to understand the reasoning behind some of the syntax and you'll love what you learn :)

Sorry if my answer is all over the place, but your question is very open ended.

The more direct answer to your question:

1. (UITableViewCell*): This is the return type. The tableView is asking
   you to create a cell and return it.
2. tableView:(UITableView *): this is the tableView for which your
   viewController is the delegate. Why are you getting a reference to
   the tableView? This is because a viewController can have multiple
   tableViews so you need to know which tableView needs stuff.
3. cellForRowAtIndexPath: The tableView is giving it's delegate more
   information that would help it cater to the request. It's telling
   the viewController the indexPath of the cell. This way, for e.g, if
   you have an NSArray as the data for the tableView, you'll know the
   index for the data to display on the tableViewCell.

Some more reading if you're interested - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: Thank you so much, this clarified it so well, I've been going crazy over this haha, this makes so so much sense though. Thank you!

Comment: No worries. Some of the Objective C documentation on the apple website does a good job explaining the syntax. It might seem a lot to type, but coding in Objective C is a breeze, and code that you write will be easily understandable by another developer because of the nature of the syntax. Also, good on you to learn Objective C, but do look at Swift as another viable alternative for a new developer.

Answer (score 0):

Objective C methods should sound like a statement or question when read.  That makes them verbose and also adds names for each of the parameters.  The big mental hurdle when learning it is that methods are actually split up.  Take your example:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

As is pointed out above, the name is not `tableView`, it is `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  Notice the colons are included in the name.  That is important, it means that an argument will be passed in.  This method has 2 colons in the name, so it will have two arguments.  Other interesting points are that the types used in this method definition are all in parenthesis and that the first character indicates what type of function it is.  `+` means class method (static function) and `-` means instance method.

If it were written in another C type language (like Java, C++ or C#) it would be

```
UITableViewCell * tableViewCellForRowAtIndexPath(UITableView *tableView, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
```

So going back to the method, let's break it down.   First, it is an instance method.  Next is the return type.  (That is unnamed.)  Now we get to the function name and arguments.  There will now be

- a lable
- a colon
- a type
- an argument

This will repeat for each argument in the method.  Going back to the example.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

- [ `-` ] It is an instance method
- [ `(UITableViewCell *)` ] It returns a pointer to an object of type UITableViewCell
- [ `tableView` ] Part of the method name

  - [ `:` ] Indicating that there is an argument coming
  - [ `(UITableView *)` ] The argument type
  - [ `tableView` ] The argument name
- [ `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ] Part of the method name

  - [ `:` ] Indicating that there is an argument coming.
  - [ `(NSIndexPath *)` ] The argument type
  - [ `indexPath` ] The argument name

The exception to the above is methods that do not take any arguments.  They will have a single label and no trailing colon or type.  i.e. `- (UIView *)view`  The name of this method is `view` (again no trailing colon in the name.)